# android - shutdown progressive spinning wheel interrupted by toast

Tags: android

I found one interesting behavior in android13.

When device shutdown, the progressive spinning wheel will be interrupted by toast.

I checked the code from [AOSP](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/globalactions/GlobalActionsImpl.java;drc=5b0a11e9766a76af52d45d11545a85b25f9165d3;l=82),

```
    public void showShutdownUi(boolean isReboot, String reason) {
        ScrimDrawable background = new ScrimDrawable();

        final Dialog d = new Dialog(mContext,
                com.android.systemui.R.style.Theme_SystemUI_Dialog_GlobalActions);

        d.setOnShowListener(dialog -> {
            if (mBlurUtils.supportsBlursOnWindows()) {
                int backgroundAlpha = (int) (ScrimController.BUSY_SCRIM_ALPHA * 255);
                background.setAlpha(backgroundAlpha);
                mBlurUtils.applyBlur(d.getWindow().getDecorView().getViewRootImpl(),
                        (int) mBlurUtils.blurRadiusOfRatio(1), backgroundAlpha == 255);
            } else {
                float backgroundAlpha = mContext.getResources().getFloat(
                        com.android.systemui.R.dimen.shutdown_scrim_behind_alpha);
                background.setAlpha((int) (backgroundAlpha * 255));
            }
        });

        // Window initialization
        Window window = d.getWindow();
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        window.getAttributes().systemUiVisibility |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        // Inflate the decor view, so the attributes below are not overwritten by the theme.
        window.getDecorView();
        window.getAttributes().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        window.getAttributes().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        window.getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_ALWAYS;
        window.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_VOLUME_OVERLAY);
        window.getAttributes().setFitInsetsTypes(0 /* types */);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        window.addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
        window.setWindowAnimations(com.android.systemui.R.style.Animation_ShutdownUi);

        d.setContentView(R.layout.shutdown_dialog);
        d.setCancelable(false);

        int color;
        if (mBlurUtils.supportsBlursOnWindows()) {
            color = Utils.getColorAttrDefaultColor(mContext,
                    com.android.systemui.R.attr.wallpaperTextColor);
        } else {
            color = mContext.getResources().getColor(
                    com.android.systemui.R.color.global_actions_shutdown_ui_text);
        }

        ProgressBar bar = d.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        bar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setTint(color);

        TextView reasonView = d.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView messageView = d.findViewById(R.id.text2);

        reasonView.setTextColor(color);
        messageView.setTextColor(color);

        messageView.setText(getRebootMessage(isReboot, reason));
        String rebootReasonMessage = getReasonMessage(reason);
        if (rebootReasonMessage != null) {
            reasonView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            reasonView.setText(rebootReasonMessage);
        }

        d.show();
    }
```

The dialog layout xml is [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/shutdown_dialog.xml;drc=0e338eeb1f51a3168b6c7b6a8f512b10df3ae1a6;l=54).

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32sp"
        android:text="@string/shutdown_progress"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:fontFamily="@string/config_headlineFontFamily"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32sp"
        android:text="@string/shutdown_progress"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:fontFamily="@string/config_headlineFontFamily"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@id/progress"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        style="?attr/progressBarStyleLarge" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The shudown dialog is defined as `TYPE_VOLUME_OVERLAY`, I try to change it to `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` , issue still happen.

Any other more higher priority type to avoid being interrupted by toast?